# What is the "1 RETURN" bug?

Tags: security, history, weaknesses

From Nathaniel Popper's *“Digital Gold : Bitcoin and the Inside Story of the Misfits and Millionaires Trying to Reinvent Money"*, this heavily edited (by me, for clarity) excerpt:

> “In late July Gavin and Satoshi got an e-mail from ...a programmer
>   from Germany going by the screen name ArtForz, ... had found a
>   previously undiscovered weakness in the code that ...made it possible
>   to spend Bitcoins in someone else’s wallet.”
>
> “For now, don’t call it the ‘1 RETURN’ bug to anyone who doesn’t
>   already know about it,” Satoshi wrote to Gavin.”

What is this `1 RETURN` bug? It's obviously been patched, but I'm interested because the book doesn't delve into technical details.

(FWIW, I highly recommend buying this book).

Comment: "In July..." What year was this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the early sources here: http://www.bitcointrading.com/forum/bitcoin-clients/original-bitcoin-source-code-archives/

there is a small piece of code in script.cpp:

```
    case OP_RETURN:
    {
        pc = pend;
    }
    break;
```

which allows to spend ANY UTXO with just a very simple scriptSig `OP_1 OP_RETURN`

Comment: Wow, what a monumental oversight. I'm not versed in C++, so can you clarify what's happening? It looks like if it's a `6a` (op_return) push code is encountered, the code breaks, leaving `op_true` on the stack, making the Tx valid?

Comment: Yes, in the early bitcoin versions `OP_RETURN` just finished the script evaluation without changing the stack value. So, the stack had 1 on the top. The other flaw in that version was concatenating scriptSig and scriptPubkey to one byte array and executing them as one script, not as two consecutive scripts. `return EvalScript(txin.scriptSig + CScript(OP_CODESEPARATOR) + txout.scriptPubKey, txTo, nIn, nHashType);` The bug was fixed by changing `OP_RETURN` opcode: now it finishes script execution as 'failed'

Comment: Wow, possibly the world's best example of Linus's Law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_law