# Why is concatenating scriptPubKeys and scriptSigs unsafe?

Tags: security, script, input-script, output-script

Around the 5:00 timestamp in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np-SCwkqVy4), John Newbery states that running the concatenation of scriptPubKey and scriptSig is unsafe, since it can result in someone using a carefully crafted scriptSig in order to spend *any* output.

What would such a scriptSig look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *was* possible (see the infamous "[`1 RETURN` bug](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38037/101498)") because the `RETURN` operand used to stop the execution of the Script. So simply pushing `1` in the scriptSig and `RETURN`ing would make the execution of the catenated `scriptSig || scriptPubKey` successful no matter the content of the scriptPubKey.

Separating both certainly makes it easier to reason about and therefore be certain it's safe from this failure mode.

---

I initially posted this answer with an assertion that once the `RETURN` operand was fixed it was unclear how you would bypass the scriptPubKey. I didn't think hard enough! Actually you could simply include a `PUSHDATA`, which would interpret the scriptPubKey as a [data array pushed on the stack](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6ce5e8f4758e6fccf59b3980af417ec6c75e383e/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L477-L481), which would then make the execution successful since it [would be casted to `true`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6ce5e8f4758e6fccf59b3980af417ec6c75e383e/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1824) [as long as it's not all `0x00`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6ce5e8f4758e6fccf59b3980af417ec6c75e383e/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L35-L48)s.

So it's true that catenating the scriptSig and the scriptPubKey is always unsafe.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that `RETURN` always implied the execution failed, since it is typically used to burn BTC. Is that what you meant by "fixing the `RETURN` operand"?

Comment: @CosmikDebris Currently it is the case that `OP_RETURN` immediately marks the transaction invalid, but the the bug under discussion is exactly that its semantics used to  simply be "stop execution" (which only resulted in failure if there was a false on top of the stack at that point). The practice of using `OP_RETURN` for burning funds came only years after this bug was fixed.