# Why are OP_MUL and OP_DIV disabled in Bitcoin?

Tags: script, attack, history, opcodes

What is the reason why `OP_MUL` and `OP_DIV` operators were removed from Bitcoin? Is this because someone could maliciously create a script that multiplies large numbers and thus blows the stack, or is there another reason (some network attack has already happened using these operators so they were thrown out)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OP_MUL` and `OP_DIV` were removed by Satoshi Nakamoto in commit [`4bd188c4383d6e614e18f79dc337fbabe8464c82`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/4bd188c4383d6e614e18f79dc337fbabe8464c82). As with most changes in early days of the development, little rationale was explicitly given by Satoshi Nakamoto for this change.

In light of the recent shortcomings with the Script interpreter (the [`1 RETURN` bug](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38037/101498) was fixed [only 10 commits (and 15 days) before](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/6ff5f718b6a67797b2b3bab8905d607ad216ee21) this change for instance and there is [more](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures)), it is often assumed Satoshi Nakamoto disabled some of the opcodes out of precaution. `OP_MUL` and `OP_DIV` were some of them.

I'm not aware of any exploitable bugs using `OP_MUL` and `OP_DIV` at the time, but the implementation of `OP_LSHIFT` (disabled in the same batch) for instance [could be remotely exploited to crash a node](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures#CVE-2010-5137).